# Упорядочить значения (value) SortedMap

Tags: сортировка, java

Здравствуйте!

Возникла проблемка.

Имеется вот такая вот Map:

```
SortedMap<String, Double> sortmap = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, упорядочить ее по *значениям*, именно по значениям, а не по ключам.

Было бы супер, если бы мы не потеряли ключи.

С уважением, Glebyshka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать хак с компоратором

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);

        map.put("A",99.5);
        map.put("B",67.4);
        map.put("C",67.4);
        map.put("D",67.3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);
    }
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

Пример взял от [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: Ну или можно Google Guava'ой воспользоваться.